# Chaining CSS keyframe animations behaves differently across browsers

Tags: css, animation, svg, cross-browser

I am trying to animate an SVG logo on load using a simple couple of CSS keyframe animations.

However on Chrome the last two elements just disappear instead of animating out, and on Safari the last few elements ignore their delay differences and all animate out simulatenously.

Only on Firefox does the entire animation behave properly.

[See the Codepen here](http://codepen.io/mattaningram/pen/OPbxgO) (open in each browser to see the differences)

I am using Autoprefixer, and from what I can see in the output CSS file it is simply creating some -webkit- prefixes and that's about it. The desired animations work on other individual elements, so the error isn't there.

Here is an example of one of the diagonal elements (the ones that have issues on Chrome) output CSS:

```
.m-logo-stroke-blue.m-logo-stroke-diag {
   -webkit-animation: fadeInDownRight 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both, fadeOutUpLeft 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53) 2.7s forwards;
   animation: fadeInDownRight 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both, fadeOutUpLeft 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53) 2.7s forwards;
}
```

Really confused as to why this isn't working properly except on Firefox.

**Edit:**

So I discovered that if I make the duration of the animation out of the diagonals LONGER than the delay, it fixes them disappearing on Chrome, but of course it makes the animation very slow. Not sure why that happens.

**Edit 2:**

Ok so my brother figured out a solution, although I really don't know why this works.

I had this:

```
.m-logo-stroke-blue {
  &.m-logo-stroke-up {
    animation: fadeInShrink .2s $easeOutQuad .6s both, fadeOutUp .2s $easeInQuad 2s forwards;
  }
  &.m-logo-stroke-across {
    animation: fadeInShrink .2s $easeOutQuad .4s both, fadeOutRight .2s $easeInQuad 2.3s forwards;
  }
  &.m-logo-stroke-diag {
    animation: fadeInDownRight .2s $easeOutQuad both, fadeOutUpLeft .2s $easeInQuad 2.7s forwards;
  }
}

.m-logo-stroke-red {
  &.m-logo-stroke-up {
    animation: fadeInShrink .2s $easeOutQuad .7s both, fadeOutUp .2s $easeInQuad 2.1s forwards;
  }
  &.m-logo-stroke-diag {
    animation: fadeInDownLeft .2s $easeOutQuad .21s both, fadeOutUpRight .2s $easeInQuad 2.8s forwards;
  }
}
```

and changed it to this:

```
.m-logo-stroke-blue {
  &.m-logo-stroke-up {
    animation: fadeInShrink .2s $easeOutQuad .6s both, fadeOutUp .2s $easeInQuad 2s forwards;
  }
  &.m-logo-stroke-across {
    animation: fadeInShrink .2s $easeOutQuad .4s both, fadeOutRight .2s $easeInQuad 2.3s forwards;
  }
  &.m-logo-stroke-diag {
    animation: fadeInDownRight .2s $easeOutQuad .21s both, fadeOutUpLeft .2s $easeInQuad 2.5s forwards;
  }
}

.m-logo-stroke-red {
  &.m-logo-stroke-up {
    animation: fadeInShrink .2s $easeOutQuad .7s both, fadeOutUp .2s $easeInQuad 2.1s forwards;
  }
  &.m-logo-stroke-diag {
    animation: fadeInDownLeft .2s $easeOutQuad .41s both, fadeOutUpRight .2s $easeInQuad 2.6s forwards;
  }
}
```

If you paste that in to the CodePen you will see it works on all browsers.

For some reason they both need a delay, and the delay has to be slightly longer? Can someone explain what is going on here?

I will post as solution if no one can explain soon.

**Edit 3:**

WTF is going on? Now it has stopped working with no change in my code. Did Chrome change how it handles chained CSS animations for the worse.

In Chrome the last animation simply doesn't run. In Safari the timing is off. In Firefox it works perfectly as before.

I am completely baffled here. Please halp.